# .Net core with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core-3.0

I am new to mongodb i am trying to insert a data into my collection using mongodb shell

User.cs

```
public class User

{

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("userName")]
    public string? UserName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("workDay")]
    public IEnumerable<WorkDay>? WorkDay { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("emailAddress")]
    public string? EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("sendEventsOutsideWorkHours")]
    public bool? SendEventsOutsideWorkHours { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("sendReportOutsideWorkHours")]
    public bool? SendReportsOutsideWorkHours { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("timeZoneOffset")]
    public int? TimeZoneOffset { get; set; }
}
```

Workday.cs

```
public class WorkDay

    [BsonElement("dayOfWeek")]
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }


    [BsonElement("startTime")]
    public WorkDayBoundary _StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime
    {
        get
        {
            return new TimeSpan(_StartTime.Hours, _StartTime.Minutes, 0);
        }
    }

    [BsonElement("endTime")]
    public WorkDayBoundary _EndTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime
    {
        get
        {
            return new TimeSpan(_EndTime.Hours, _EndTime.Minutes, 0);
        }
    }
}

public class WorkDayBoundary
{
    [BsonElement("hours")]
    public int Hours { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("minutes")]
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my code in mongodb shell

```
db.Users.insertMany([{
    'userName': 'Testing123',
    'workDay': {
        'dayOfWeek': 0,
        'startTime': { 'hours': 5, 'minutes': 23 },
        'endTime': { 'hours': 5, 'minutes': 23 }
    },
    'emailAddress': 'thisismymail@email.com',
    'sendEventsOutsideWorkHours': 1,
    'sendReportOutsideWorkHours': 1,
    'timeZoneOffset': 5.00
},
{
    'userName': 'Something999',
    'workDay': {
        'dayOfWeek': 1,
        'startTime': { 'hours': 1, 'minutes': 55 },
        'endTime': { 'hours': 10, 'minutes': 33 }
    },
    'emailAddress': 'somethingas@email@email.com',
    'sendEventsOutsideWorkHours': 0,
    'sendReportOutsideWorkHours': 0,
    'timeZoneOffset': 2.00
}
])
```

and while executing from `.netcore application` it was throwing an exception as

```
 "FormatException: Cannot deserialize a 'List<WorkDay>' from BsonType 'Document'."
```

Comment: What does your query look like in your application?

Comment: Something I have noticed about C# developers trying to use MongoDB - they don't like to have a property in their class called "_id", they seem to always change it to "id".  My advice for this particular concept is to adopt using "_id" as the property name in your C# models.

Comment: Also, because you are having serialization problems, I would add a constructor that sets property `public IEnumerable<WorkDay>? WorkDay { get; set; }` to a new `List<WorkDay>` to avoid null references.  I have seen this type of error using WebAPI too.

Comment: @barrypicker tried changing those changes in my application but it throwing same exception System.FormatException: 'An error occurred while deserializing the WorkDay property of class CustomerPortalSubscriptionService.Models.User: Cannot deserialize a 'List<WorkDay>' from BsonType 'Document'.'

Comment: When looking at the sample documents you show in the insertMany() the 'workDay' is not an array, it is merely a sub document.  For this reason the model binder cannot cast the sub document into an IEnumerable.  Change the IEnumerable to a standard type or change the data in the document to be an array of sub documents.

Comment: @barrypicker "workDay" is an array i missed some braces, so it is throwing an exception. It worked Thanks a lot for helping me out this. Thank You once again